# Questions Regarding Mathematical Software

Tags: discussion

My instinct on [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3315409/about-squarefree-numbers) was to close it because it was about the MATLAB software. To be sure I was making the right choice, I wanted to verify that it was off-topic and not about mathematics as defined within the [help center](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), but I found that questions regarding software mathematicians use are *on topic* on the main site. As a result, I decided not to cast a vote to close. The question, then, is:

> What types of questions are allowed/encouraged on the the main site regarding mathematical software?

Regardless of the answer, should we update the help center to clarify what is expected in such a question?

For reference, this type of question has been asked before (see [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9073/do-we-actually-welcome-questions-about-software-that-mathematicians-use), for example). The questions I found about the topic seemed to be rather old, and there don't seem to be clear guidelines about what types of questions or what content the question ought to have to meet the community standards.

Comment: The main question you asked is somewhat recurring.  It came up again recently https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30315/can-we-ask-about-code-in-math-stackexchange, and I'd consider the very well-received answer of Asaf there as the main guiding principle:  For the specific question I'd say it is more to the off-topic side. Would they not specify the language it'd be maybe alright. For updating the help center, yes, that might be a good idea. For the time being I promoted the question quoted above to a FAQ.

Comment: Thanks, @quid. I missed that question; the ones that showed up in my search queries were several years old.